# Stash Nested Append List with Matrix and Playa

Tags: matrix, playa, stash

I have a channel with a matrix field named `expedition_days`, and inside of that matrix, there is a playa column named `resources`. I am trying to create a stash list for each row of the matrix. It seems like you can't use the playa module tags inside of append_list, unless I'm missing something.

```
{exp:channel:entries
    channel="expedition"
    dynamic="no"
    limit="1"
}
    {expedition_days}
        {exp:stash:append_list
            name="expedition_days"
            parse_tags="yes"
        }
            {stash:item_day}{row_count}{/stash:item_day}
            {stash:item_location}{location}{/stash:item_location}

            {exp:playa:children
                col="resources"
            }
                {exp:stash:append_list:nested name="resources_{row_count}"}
                    {stash:item_title}{title}{/stash:item_title}
                {/exp:stash:append_list:nested}
            {/exp:playa:children}
        {/exp:stash:append_list}
    {/expedition_days}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually realized that the nested list is completely unnecessary. Since I am building the list off of the matrix row, I can simplify it to be this:

```
{exp:channel:entries
    channel="expedition"
    dynamic="no"
    limit="1"
}
    {expedition_days}
        {exp:stash:append_list name="expedition_days"}
            {stash:item_day}{row_count}{/stash:item_day}
            {stash:item_location}{location}{/stash:item_location}
        {/exp:stash:append_list}

        {resources}
            {exp:stash:append_list name="resources_{row_count}"}
                {stash:item_title}{title}{/stash:item_title}
            {/exp:stash:append_list}
        {/resources}
    {/expedition_days}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 2):

Whenever I encounter these parse order issues with Stash, I find it helps to promote your Stash tags higher up the nesting hierarchy. Remember that the `set` and `set_list` methods automatically detect tags that loop, so often, you won't need to use the append methods. Try this for example:

```
{exp:channel:entries
    channel="expedition"
    dynamic="no"
    limit="1"
}

    {exp:stash:set_list name="expedition_days" parse_tags="yes"}
        {expedition_days}
            {stash:item_day}{row_count}{/stash:item_day}
            {stash:item_location}{location}{/stash:item_location}

            {exp:stash:set_list:2 parse_tags="yes" name="resources_{row_count}"}
                {exp:playa:children col="resources"}
                    {stash:item_title}{title}{/stash:item_title}
                {/exp:playa:children}
            {/exp:stash:set_list:2}

        {/expedition_days}
    {/exp:stash:set_list}

{/exp:channel:entries}

{!-- ==============================
TEST OUTPUT 
=================================== --}

{exp:stash:parse process="end"}
    <ul>
    {exp:stash:get_list name="expedition_days"}
        <li>
            <h3>day: {item_day} - location: {item_location}</h3>
            <ul>
              {exp:stash:get_list:2 name="resources_{item_day}"}
                 <li>{item_title}</li>
              {/exp:stash:get_list:2}
            </ul>
        </li>
    {/exp:stash:get_list}
    </ul>
{/exp:stash:parse}
```

Also, are you sure you want to use the `playa:children` tag? I don't know what your exact use-case is here, but you may find that using the simple primary tag pair (`{resources}...{/resources}`) gives you what you're looking for (assuming you're trying to output each row's related items, as opposed to the entire set of relationships in the column, which is what the `playa:children` tag will do).

Comment: Just a note to point out that the Playa field replaces those `{related}...{/related}` tag pairs with `{exp:playa:children row_id="n" col="resources"}...{/exp:playa:children}` in any case. Trevor is just missing the `row_id ="{row_id}"` parameter, I think.